# Add weekno for 2 years data

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

How to add weekno for two years data, for the records in second year should have weekno starting from 54 as first year has 53 weeks.

I used

```
to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'WW+53') as weekno
```

but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_number(to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'WW'))+53 as weekno
```

But better using IYYY and IW for proper week numbering.

```
case to_number(to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'IYYY')) 
  when 2012 then to_number(to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'IW'))
  when 2013 then to_number(to_char(to_date(TRANSDATE, 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'IW')) + 52
end as weekno
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
One more question,
my data starts from apr 2010 and ends in dec 2011,
so how to give week no 1 to apr01 and corresponding week to record in dec 2011?